# "Резиновые" блоки

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вот вопрос.
Есть два дива:

```
.menuLeft {
    background: #2980b9;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 210px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
.menuRight {
    background: #3498db;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 1075px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
```

как вы уже поняли, это два блока, один выводиться слева другой справа.
Вывожу я их просто:
`echo '<div class="menuLeft">Левое меню</div>';`
`echo '<div class="menuRight">Правое меню</div>';`
нужно чтоб блоки были "резиновые", а именно, если у пользователя монитор меньше - то чтоб блоки не ложились друг на друга или же чтоб не съезжали.
Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет! Предлагаю обернуть твои блоки ещё одним блоком оберткой. Которому задаешь ширину в 100%.

для своего левого блока - ширину прописываешь в процентах, например, 30%, для правого - соответственно - 70%.

Для левого блока - позиция `position:fixed;` правый - `position: relative;`

и тягаем :)

Код: https://jsfiddle.net/dj0krho6/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menuLeft">Левое меню</div>
    <div class="menuRight">Правое меню</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.menuLeft {
    background: #2980b9;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px; 
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
}

.menuRight {
    background: #3498db;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: `fixed` привяжет позицию блоков к экрану, а не к странице. Правильнее будет всё же `absolute`.

Comment: Да, Согласна. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте задать ширину в процентах.

Comment: пробывал - при увеличении масштаба правый блок съезжает ниже левого

Comment: Учитывайте padding или пропишите блокам свойство box-sizing: border-box; тогда в ширину будут входить padding и border, но margin нужно будет учесть.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `float` прописать обоим блокам `position: absolute`, потом левому `left: 0px`, правому соответственно `right: 0px`. Ширину блоков в процентах по вкусу, а чтоб они не налазили друг на друга, добавить над ними еще один `<div>`:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menuLeft">Левое меню</div>
  <div class="menuRight">Правое меню</div>
<div>

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px; /* подобрать правильную минимальную ширину, в зависимости 
                         от установок ширины левого и правого блоков */
}
```